# Unity, mobile, how to access location in background?

Tags: unity

How can I access location on mobile in the background in Unity?

My use case is for geofencing, while the app is running in the background (eg. phone may be locked), check if the user is within a certain area every now and again, and if they are, alert them with a notification.

I have a vague idea that I could do this by

1. Write a native plugin for iOS that does this
2. Write a native plugin for Android that does this
3. Call them from unity.

There's an old guide for this approach.

https://github.com/devhelpme/unity-bg-location/

https://web.archive.org/web/20171127071251/http://www.devhelp.me/unity-background-location-service-step-by-step/

But that would be a tonne of work. I can't find any asset that does this. An asset of this would be so handy.

Can you recommend anything or just give me any leads? thanks!

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html

Comment: @Zibelas I know from experience it's definitely not possible on mobile without a native plugin.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I copied the code from their documentation and it works on android without any problem. You just need to grant the rights to use the locations

Comment: @Zibelas "IN BACKGROUND" please read the question before typing.

Comment: @GuyeIncognito if you find users seem to be overlooking a key part of your question, that's often a sign that you can improve it with an edit. You could try stating this requirement more explicitly, like "While my app is minimized / not in focus, I want to be able to detect that the player is in a location and send them a notification if so". This can help remove any ambiguity, since "in background" can also mean doing something on a background thread even while your app is in focus.

Comment: AFAIK, Unity will pause the "game" when it's in the background (and from a quick search I've found it ignores runinbackground on Android and iOS). If we oversimplify you have to have another app run in the background and that app has to do the work you're talking about and they have to communicate with each other. So, the question could be more generalized to "How to run the game in the background on Android" and the answer is you can't. I think this post from stackoverflow explains things nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453605/android-unity-app-running-in-background

Comment: @JohnHamilton You can run native code in the background on Android and iOS from Unity. I have done it. It just needs to be a native plugin.. Its also possible to use these plugins to run C# code from your unity project. Anyway with these native plugins all sorts of things are possible in the background on mobile (eg playing audio) + my use case. Just implementing my use case from scratch would be a lot of work, though I could do it if I had to. I have done similar things in the past. My use case is dealing with location and notifications which are native things anyway.